# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn’t find “libLiteCoreJNI.so” when initializing CBLite

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

CouchbaseLite.init(getApplicationContext());//error occurs here

log:-
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ex.abc-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ex.abc-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ex.abc-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libLiteCoreJNI.so"

Comment: Hey @Monika, this is pretty weird: Can you provide a little more information?  What kind of system is running this code?  What version of Couchbase Lite are you running?  Where did you get the copy of the couchbase library that you included in your application?

Comment: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-liblitecorejni-so-when-initializing-cblite/29007/6  you can refer to the details mentioned here. Thank you for your response.

Comment: It is true, I can.  It would be very helpful, for anyone *else* that finds this issue, if you included the details.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the question here. Did you actually find the .so on the disk but the loader could find it?

Comment: No, I did not find the .so. Can you help me at the location I need to check the .so on the disk?